# Intel HD 3000 driver update dropped windows 7 rating

Tags: windows-7, graphics, intel-graphics

I have HP dv6 i7 2670qm with HD 3000.Yesterday I installed updates for HD 3000 from Intel site after uninstalling previous drivers.After installing updated drivers I got message that the drivers are not supported by my laptop so I uninstalled updated drivers. Windows automatically reinstalled the previous drivers after reboot. But my windows Index rating for Intel graphics went down to 4.8 for aero and 6.2 for gaming from 5.9 to aero and 6.5 gaming. I want to know what wrong did I do? How can I regain my previous rating?

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Ratings doesn't mean anything. Just ignore them, seriously. If you want a score that means _anything_, use SiSoftware Sandra, PCMark, 3DMark or any trustworthy benchmark applications.

Comment: Another reason driver updates are not always beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

On a not very serious note:
It's possible to [manually edit the XML that sets the WEI scores](http://www.howtogeek.com/71500/stupid-geek-tricks-hacking-the-windows-experience-index/) or even use [an automated tool](http://www.jtechsoftwares.in/windows-rating-changer.html) to do the same.

This probably should give you a hint at how meaningful and important the index score actually is. But it can be done if, for some reason, you'd want to. :)